# Make the most of your gift to the Foundation by doubling it today

Tags: phrase-meaning

I don't understand the phrase "Make the most of your gift to the Foundation by doubling it today" - Usually, "make it to" means "come to somewhere" - so okay, you come to the foundation (and donate it?). But how do you "double it"? You donate $100 and get $200 back? I have no clue what it means.

What does the phrase mean then?

> Richard Dawkins tweeted just now
> The $50,000 matching gift offer expires with the end of the year, but you still have time. **Make the most of your gift to the Richard Dawkins Foundation by doubling it today**: http://richarddawkins.net/year-end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not "make it to", but "make the most of"  Which means "get the greatest benefit from"

So you can get the greatest benefit of your gift to this foundation if you  "double it today".   Here you need to read a bit of the context to understand what it means.

There is an offer that if you donate £100 before the end of the year, then that donation will be matched.  This means that if you donate £100 today, the foundation will receive £200.  This is done because a rich person wants to encourage other people to donate.  The "rich person" is actually "Richard Dawkins".

You donate £100, Richard Dawkins also donates £100  the foundation gets double the donation.  You make the most of your gift by donating this year, and not in January.

Comment: Arguably, this use of "make the most of" is slightly unusual, in that the gift-giver isn't deriving any direct benefit from the gift.  I'd probably have written "Help the Foundation to make the most of your gift" instead.

Comment: Thank you.   There is a minor question that I am still not clear of. That is the use of "to" - "get the greatest benefit of your gift to this foundation": why not "get the greatest benefit of your gift from this foundation"? You donate  £100 - that is the sum of your contribution to the foundation and by doing so you trigger the mechanism of doubling (someone will match your sum by donating  £100 too). So you get the benefit - the credit of contributing the foundation.  Is my understanding correct here?

Comment: Well, your gift is from you "to the foundation"  It is the foundation that benefits. I suppose you benefit indirectly (if you support the work of the foundation), but the foundation gets the money, not you.

Comment: @rjpond I don't think it's unusual at all - if the gift-giver didn't derive *any* benefit, they wouldn't be donating to that nonprofit. Regardless of their reasoning for wanting to donate, presumably if they were happy with the foundation receiving $x, they'd be happier with the foundation receiving $2x. Makes perfect sense to me!

Comment: @rjpond "Make the most of X" doesn't mean "make it so you derive the greatest benefit from X". It means "make X as useful as possible". You don't have to be deriving the benefit to be making the most of it.

Comment: @Accumulation You could be right there, although "get the greatest benefit from" was James K's definition and not (or not just) mine.  It certainly is a definition that fits the vast majority of the instances that I come across, though.

Answer (score 4):

No, someone is offering to match all donations raised (up to 50K) for a limited time. So if you donate $100, they would match it so the foundation would get a total of $200. So that's the doubling.

Answer (score 0):

*What should I do?*
`Make` *(verb)*

*What does that apply to?*
   `the most`  *(direct object)*

*The most of what?*
      `of your gift` *(prepositional adjectival phrase)*

*Which gift, i.e. to whom?*
         `to the Richard Dawkins Foundation` *(prepositional adjectival phrase)*

*How do I do this?*
   `by doubling it` *(prepositional adverbial phrase)*

*When do I do this?*
   `today` *(adverb)*